# Should I handle all nine comparisons?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I was reading this article here: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/08/domain-object-base-class/.  The article talks about creating a base Entity class, which handles four of the nine ways to do comparison in C# i.e. it handles:

```
==
!=
object.Equals
IEquatable<T>.Equals<T>
```

Then I read this article here: https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/

The first author is talking specifically about Domain Driven Design.  Therefore I am inclined to handle the four comparisons he handles.  Also it does not sound natural for a Customer to be less than or equal to another Customer and it does not sound natural for a Product to be less than or equal to another Product (as it stands).  The only data structures I have used so far is Lists and HashSets.

Should I handle four comparisons or nine?

Comment: Which comparisons do you use in your code? If you never use `IEquatable<T>.Equals`, for example, why waste time implementing it? As for the first article: any article that starts by suggesting inheritance be used goes straight in the bin in my view. Implementing an interface is **not** a violation of DRY. Rubbish article.

Comment: Does your application have any reason to compare the Customer to another Customer in any sense beyond equal/not equal? If not, don't cause problems by trying to shoehorn it in. If it ever comes up, add it in.

Comment: @David Arno, I assume you are against the Entity base type and Value Object base type? Is that right? There are other authors who suggest this approach as well e.g. this one: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/06/25/generic-value-object-equality/

Comment: `BaseX` classes are the seed of the evil. Overall when it comes to the domain data model. In the 99% of the cases I have used them, they were totally unecessary.

Comment: @Laiv, are you referring to a base class for Entity and ValueObject (like in my first link) i.e. are you saying you find them unnecessary?

Comment: Yes. For example that IEntity. As I commented, in most of the cases you will not need such abstraction. You will realise that half of the entities don't need half of the interface's methods. Or some methods need to be partialy adapted. Run away from such practices. Keep it simple.

Comment: @Laiv, thanks.  Can you recall any scenario when Entity (I assume you mean Entity and not IEntity) were useful and what was the circumstances?

Comment: Nop. Basically because "what does Entity means"? If you ask to your Ubiquitous Language, you will find no answer. Base classes as such are often used for DRY and that's a very bad argument for inheritance.

Comment: The question seems to be built on a general "if you build it, they will come" attitude. Is this a given, or can we point out that this is at odds with an agile approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also it does not sound natural for a Customer to be less than or equal to another Customer and it does not sound natural for a Product to be less than or equal to another Product (as it stands).

If your entities are not ordered in the domain that you are trying to model, there's not a lot of value in creating a bunch of comparison functions.

More broadly, we don't normally order entities anyway, except that we impose an order on them by examining their inner properties (order by age, order alphabetically by family name, etc), which are typically values.

Eric Evans, in [his pluralsight course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRCOKKUSp9s)

> I have come to believe that an entity shouldn't even have an equality comparison

The writers at Gridshore [offer a longer analysis](https://www.gridshore.nl/2009/07/29/domain-driven-design-and-the-equals-method/).

One of the answers they propose is to use an intention revealing interface.  For instance, if what you actually care about in your domain model is whether two entities share the same identity, then you should have them provide a [sameIdentityAs](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/shared/Entity.java#L15) method, rather than leaning on the domain agnostic spelling "equals".

I don't believe that delivers as much value as you would expect, in practice.  Establishing "identity" usually means comparing different values within the object.  For entities that have a concept of identity, the compared value usually is the value representation of identity.

Which is to say, there is a (logical) mapping function that allows you to access the mutable state of the entity given the correct immutable key, and `sameIdentityAs` is normally going to be a simply mapping to equality of the key.  Which means it will be unusual to need to compare two *entities* for equality without already having access to the *keys* that you would need to do so.

> It requires code outside of Customer be responsible for determining if two customer objects are the same. Sounds a bit "anaemic" to me...

It does -- and to be honest; the more I learn about the topic, the less concerned I become with the "anaemic" label.  Domain state and domain behaviors should be separable *behind the abstraction that the application interacts with*.

Note the distinction: we're keeping all of this code within the domain model; then there's the secondary question of does it improve the design to isolate these choices in a "customer" model.

Comment: I don't have sound on this PC so I will watch that video later.  Is he against all equality e.g. Object.Equals, IEquality.Equals etc? Thanks

Comment: @w0051977 no, it's saying no `customer1 == customer2` calls. Instead you would use `customer1.Id == customer2.Id` or `customer1.Address == customer2.Address` etc, with different equalities in different situations

Comment: "*I have come to believe that an entity shouldn't even have an equality comparison*" How does he propose determining if a customer already exists then?

Comment: @DavidArno Check a property of the Customer (an ID of some sort) rather than the entire Customer object.

Comment: @Deacon, that's sounds like the opposite of what is preached by the whole "rich domain model" religion of DDD. It requires code outside of `Customer` be responsible for determining if two customer objects are the same. Sounds a bit "anaemic" to me...

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, I have asked a follow on question here if you would like to answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/199871/voiceofunreason

Comment: @Deacon you would want to be able to find duplicates. Say you give customers a discount if they buy for more than £1000 in a year, and then you have the same customer twice with 700 and 800 in sales.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you have two protocols, equatable and comparable. Equatable requires == and !=, or only one because one can be derived from the other. Comparable adds <=, <, >, >= and sometimes <=>, and again some can be implemented in terms of the others. Like a >= b is the same as b <= a.