# Entity and Value Object are not part of the Ubiqtious language. Should this stop me from using them?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I was talking to a Business Analyst about our Domain Model a few weeks ago.  I used a class diagram to facilitate communication.  She understands UML at a high level and this worked out quite well.  She only asked two questions: what is an Entity and what is a Value Object? I explained.

I have two base classes i.e. Entity (http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/08/domain-object-base-class/) and Value Object (https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/06/25/generic-value-object-equality/).  This seems to be working very well today.

However, a couple of people criticized this approach earlier on my other question here: [Should I handle all nine comparisons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364870/should-i-handle-all-nine-comparisons).  They argued that these bases classes:

1) Make the Domain Model anaemic as another class is responsible for comparisons.
2) Entity and Value Object are not part of the Ubiquitous language

Point two has some bearing for me because of the conversation I had with the Business Analyst.  Therefore I have looked at examples of DDD apps on GitHub with this in mind and I can't find any real life examples that use this approach.  However, some tutorial type apps use it like this one: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/tree/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common

Therefore I have to ask if this is a valid approach for a real life application or whether it is just a thought exercise?

It does not really matter whether or not I use these base types at the moment.  However, I don't want to introduce problems now that only become apparent when the application scales more in future.

Comment: why do you create a 'value object' when c# has structs?

Comment: @Ewan, I am talking about a Value Object rather than a Value Type.  Please see the second link in my question.

Comment: I have read the 2007 blog post you link to. It just mentions the 16byte limit. which is out of date and not really a limit in any case. Why do _you_ require a 'value object'?

Comment: That article is 11 years old! Do not trust such ancient articles to advise on important things like how to implement a concept in a language. C# struct can be any size, declared read-only and even passed around by reference these days.

Comment: @Ewan, I am just following advice from a few courses I have recently done mainly on Pluralsight.  Having base types allows you to create default implementations for comparisons e.g. .equals, ==, != etc.  All the value objects I have created so far and all the entities I have created so far seem suited to this approach.

Comment: Operators are not very explicit, you should avoid it. Maybe `equality` not.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding you right, every class in your domain is based on on of two classes.

1. Entity which enforces a single type Id field, tightly coupled to your database and various equality overrides and reflection of classes
2. Value which emulates a value type and attempts to enforce immutably

I am struggling to understand the motivations for this idea.

The Entity suggestion seems to be a throw back to the Active record pattern, with its tight coupling to Nhibernate, assumption that your primary key can be a long int for all objects and that a value of 0 means the object isn't 'real' because the database needs to generate ids.

The Value object seems like a clumsy attempt to replace struct. You are worried about > 16byte structs being slow and replacing them with reflection?

Both override operators, something that it rarely advisable.

There are some edge cases where you will lament that you business object is a reference class and want to create a copy constructor.

There are some rare edge cases where you want to compare objects and simply comparing the Id isn't enough.

But these aren't the kind of massive unforeseen 'gotchas' that require you to plan the entire structure of your code ahead incase they turn up.

The distinction between Value and Reference Types shouldn't be something that comes up in a discussion with a Business Analyst.

**Update : Summary of the comments**

When comparing domain objects in your application my recommendation is to compare the Id fields ie.

```
var cust1 = repo.GetCustomerByName(name);
var cust2 = repo.GetCustomerByLastName(lastname);

var areCustomersTheSame = cust1.Id == cust2.Id
```

rather than comparing the objects directly. ie.

```
var cust1 = repo.GetCustomerByName(name);
var cust2 = repo.GetCustomerByLastName(lastname);

var areCustomersTheSame = cust1 == cust2
```

The second method requires that you override the default operators which is more work and will not be expected. Additionally it means you cant do the default compare to see if the reference is the same.

There is a third complication where the Ids may match but some other fields on the object have changed, or you have no Id field at all. Here I would encapsulate that logic in another class.

```
CustomerComparer.IsAllFieldsMatch(cust1,cust2)
```

My General feeling is that if you are having to check whether objects are the same often in your Business Logic. You are doing something wrong somewhere. Get Objects once, do your thing and dispose of them.

Comment: Mark Seeman talks about it more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326288/implementing-ddd-entity-class-in-c-sharp and it is also talked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656050/is-it-better-to-have-a-baseentity-type-or-interface-that-all-entities-derive-fro

Comment: jeeze that question is even older than your blog post. I go back to my initial comment. why do _YOU_ need it? What does it achieve in _YOUR_ code.

Comment: it provides a base implementation for the Entities and Value Objects meaning comparisons are simpler.  I guess the alternative is to copy and paste all the comparison methods into all the entities and value objects? Is there another alternative.

Comment: no its just compare the id. if(cust1.Id == cust2.Id) {...}

Comment: There would be a .equals in every class though.  Is that right?

Comment: no! just compare the id field with the default comparison

Comment: I realise I would have to compare the ID.  Were would .equals be defined if there is no Entity class? Surely; in the Customer class; Order class; Order Item class; Inventory class etc.  Thanks again.

Comment: dont define it. leave equals alone

Comment: then the objects will only be equal if the references are equal, which I don't think is right?

Comment: why dont you think that is right?

Comment: Because two objects will not return true for .equals when the references are different but the IDs are the same.

Comment: like every other reference type in the world

Comment: But I thought two objects should be equal if they have the same ID (as explained in the Pluralsight course).  That is why the Entity object exists: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/08/domain-object-base-class/

Comment: That is a lot of work, and has a lot of downsides compared to just comparing the ids instead of the objects. Don't do it.

Comment: Ewan, I think I understand what you are saying now.  I think you are saying just compare the IDs in the code as and when it is needed rather than have specific methods like .equals etc.

Comment: @w0051977, if you have two entities, with the same ID, but different eg family names, then the default equality functions will say they are different; yours will say they are the same. If, for you, the latter is *always* the correct comparison (if the ID's are equal, the entities are the same, regardless of other data), then there is merit to the base-class + equality override approach. So simply ask yourself, is it always the correct comparison.

Comment: @David Arno, the Entity class would be the base implementation.  If Customer wanted to override .equals e.g. because FirstName, Surname and DateOfBirth mean a match, then it could override the .equals method itself.  Do you agree with that?

Comment: @w0051977 that sounds like the worst of both worlds

Comment: @Caleth, what would be the best of both worlds?

Comment: @w0051977 I'm not sure there is one. It's a trade-off. Having the language default of reference equality, and then a bag of `IEqualityComparer<T> where T : Entity` instances is probably the least surprising

Comment: @Caleth, that would make the Entity class worthwhile then.  Is that right?

Comment: In the case where *in general* entities can exist as multiple (reference unequal) objects, with potentially different (non-id) values, but you want to consider Id equality, and other equalities. Otherwise just have a bunch of `IEqualityComparer<T>`s

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72447/discussion-on-answer-by-ewan-entity-and-value-object-are-not-part-of-the-ubiqtio).

Comment: @Ewan, I am going back through some of my historic questions that I did not accept +1.  Before I accept - say I wanted to add entities to a set, how would I implement equality here? IEqualityComparer?

Answer (score 4):

> Entity and Value Object are not part of the Ubiqtious language. Should this stop me from using them?

You shouldn't be using terms from the implementation domain to try to explain what's going on in the business domain.

`Entity` and `Value Object` are names for implementation patterns, much like `Iterator`, `Command`, `Domain Model`....

Another way of thinking of `Entity` and `ValueObjects` is that they describe [roles](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html) that the implementations can play.  For instance, if `CustomerProfile` is an `Entity`, then that could mean that it implements an `identity()` method that returns some identifier that is a `Value Object`, which in turn promises that the identifier is immutable, and suitable for use as key into a data structure.  So you can build a generic `Repository` that can act like an in memory collection of an object that implements the Entity role by providing an identifier that supports the Value Object role

```
interface Entity<Id implements ValueObject> {...}

interface CustomerProfile {...}

HibernateCustomerProfile implements CustomerProfile, Entity<HibernateCustomerId> {...}

class HibernateCustomerProfileRepository extends Repository<CustomerProfile> {...}
```

But these conveniences are almost always down in the plumbing, not part of implementing the domain behaviors.

> Is it suitable to use ValueObject and Entity bases classes in a real implementation or is it just a thought exercise? Do you use them?

I don't use them as base classes; I normally work in languages where I'm restricted to a single base class for any given implementation, and the value of a common base class doesn't offset the costs.

As interfaces, they are just metadata.  They don't have any state of their own.

In an implementation language with mixins, they might be useful.  I'm skeptical, but I don't have enough experience with them to advertise an informed opinion.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it suitable to use ValueObject and Entity bases classes in a real implementation or is it just a thought exercise? Do you use them?

Comment: Can you answer the question in my comment above before I mark the answer?

Comment: @w0051977 Note that VoiceOfUnreason, more or less, has answered the same I commented to you couple days ago in a different question. Base classes like these barely offset the costs. However I see you exceptical to believe it. I encourage you to find it out. Do implement these base classes and Interfaces and after several development iterations make your own conclusions. You might have modeled the cases where these makes a lot of sense and are valuable. But if during the iterations you find yourself refactoring the hierarchy of classes due to the constraints imposed by the base classes...

Comment: You will understand the feeling VoiceOfUnreason and me have regarding these classes. You have to get into the conclusion by your own experience. This can not be learnt reading books, posts or forums.